# coldfusion url decode extended ascii

Tags: url, coldfusion

This seems trivial

```
<cfset username = urldecode(url.username, "utf-8")>
```

Where username in the URL = `%F8yvind`

```
Decoded username = �yvind
```

How do I get the corresponding html entity: `&#248;`?

I need to use the username as a lookup value in the db.

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose you are handling some kind of login form. If this is correct, you'd better use FORM scope instead.

Comment: I'm using a webservice and the username is coming through the URL.  Password is encrypted of course.  But, username is not.

Answer (score 3):

```
<cfset username = htmlEditFormat(urlDecode(URL.username, "utf-8"))>
```

Does this work?

Comment: Or, perhaps, the opposite? `urlDecode(htmlEditFormat(URL.username),"utf-8")`